# Site Title missing from team sites

Tags: 2013

I have a migrated SP 2010 -> 2013 environment where all the team sites which were migrated and upgraded are missing the site title. If I create a NEW team site, the site title shows up just fine on the ribbon.

I've tried going to Site Settings -> Look & Feel -> Title, description, and logo and re-setting the site title, but it still doesn't show.

Any idea how I can bring the site title back?

Comment: have you check to see if you're css might be conflicting the 2013 version?

Comment: I had the same issue using a migration tool. I had to change the settings to force the title to be migrated otherwise it wouldn't show. Are you using a migration tool?

Answer (score 3):

In SharePoint 2013 the css class that effect the title is ms-breadcrumb-top. The css id and classes that effect the title displayed is ms-core-pageTitle(class) and pageTitle(id). Try messing with those. Also try visibility:visible!important; and see what happens.

Comment: For a particular subsite, how do I access this CSS in SP Designer?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by this comment so bear with me? Did you customize your css file? If so, where ever you saved the css file (should be within your site) just right-click and open with SP Designer.

If you're talking about coreV15.css file it should be in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES (this location is by default unless moved by you).

Comment: No, I don't have any custom CSS. This is a migrated environment.

Comment: Oh. That is weird. I found this link: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/2709c5e6-0387-4230-a8a1-245586d37d31/site-title-not-showing?forum=sharepointgeneral 


I hope it helps.

Comment: Doesn't really help :( I can't really re-create just particular sites in a collection...

Comment: Sorry I was of no help. Try doing the process again. A kind of "restart" if you will.

Answer (score 1):

have you looked at the masterpage that your using? is it custom? if so change it to a default masterpage and see the result!

to me when you migrate the site and use the default masterpage it has undesiered effects on the page. Changing the master page to a default will show you if its the case, as it works fine when creating a site to me indicates a masterpage or css issue! In your old inviroment did you use a custom masterpage and when creating a new site is it using the default masterpage?

if its not a custom masterpage than you need to look at the new site you made to test. Open developer tools (f12) and inspect the title element to see where it resides and what its css looks like.... now copy the id of the title and goto the migrated site and look at the page in f12 developer, on the right hand side search for the id in the html page to see if the tag exists and see its css if its correct (same) or not, look to see if there are any other css files the page is inheriting from.

if all else fails:

http://sharepointcherie.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/sharepoint-2013-upgraded-sites-missing.html

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to us.
Map a drive to your site and copy default.aspx

```
net use z: http://...
copy z:default.aspx
notepad default.aspx

Locate the <label class="ms-hidden"> tag.
remove the class and leave just <label>
copy default.aspx z:
```

Your title is back.  I don't know how to do this globally.

Answer (score 0):

create a js script in masterpage and use rest api to get the site title

try this code:

//get site title

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "../_api/web/title",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        var siteTitleData = JSON.stringify(data);
        var siteTitleDataParsing = JSON.parse(siteTitleData);
        var siteTitle = siteTitleDataParsing.d.Title;
        $("#pageTitle").text(siteTitle);            
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("Something Went Wrong!Please Refresh Browser");
    }
    });
```